# How to test input and output overloaded operator in C++ Gtest

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, googletest

I am using following example from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/input_output_operators_overloading.htm)

Consider I have following class

```
#include <iostream>

class Distance {
private:
  int feet;             
  int inches;           

public:
  Distance()             : feet(), inches() {}
  Distance(int f, int i) : feet(f), inches(i) {}

  friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &output, const Distance &D )
  { 
     output << "F : " << D.feet << " I : " << D.inches;
     return output;            
  }

  friend std::istream &operator>>( std::istream  &input, Distance &D )
  { 
     input >> D.feet >> D.inches;
     return input;            
  }
};
```

I am using Gtest to test this class.

But I could not find better way to test it.

I can use the macro provided in gtest `ASSERT_NO_THROW`, but it will not validate the values.
Is there any way I can use `EXPECT_EQ` instead?

Thanks

Comment: Just looking at this one example I can already tell you that this tutorial is bad and teaches C++ that professionals will frown upon. Get [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/140719) instead!

Comment: @sbi, I know, I just wanted to give simple example to explain my problem.

Comment: Could you please post your testing code also? I'd go for testing using a `std::istringstream`, `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: @Rohit: I have edited your question so that the class now uses [initialization lists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1711990/140719). Feel free to disagree with my formatting, but without the initialization lists the code was just awful. And see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/140719) for why `using namespace std` is bad.

Comment: @sbi I agree code was awful. My apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way I can use EXPECT_EQ instead?

You can use a `stringstream` to print the results of `operator<<` to a string, then compare the string.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream

```
TEST( Distance, Output )
{
    std::ostringstream out;
    Distance d;
    out << d;
    EXPECT_EQ( "F:0 I:0", out.str() );
}
```

Input test would be similar, just use `std::istringtream` instead.

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to test about the operators?

- *That the stream is in a good state after writing to or reading from it.*
  You can check for that.
- *That the output operator writes a particular string for a particular distance.*
  You can do this by writing into a `std::ostringstream` and comparing the result of calling its `str()` member with your expectations.
- *That the input iterator reads a particular distance from a particular string.*
  You can do this employing a `std::istringstream` initialized with the string, comparing the distance read from it with what you expect.
- *That the class eats its own dog food.*
  Use a `std::stringstream` to write into, then read from it, and compare what you read with what you wrote.
  <sup><sub>*Note:* This will currently fail.</sub></sup>